# Monthly revenue forecasting in Salesforce

Tags: reporting, custom

Is it possible to implement monthly revenue forecasting in Salesforce without an app/managed package.

We are currently data loading revenue forecasts to custom monthly currency fields (Jan Revenue, Feb Revenue ect) but this obviously has limitations from a reporting perspective as these fields are not mapped to dates ect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The latest iteration of forecasting at the time of this answer is called [Collaborative Forecasting](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.forecasts3_overview.htm&type=5). This is fully native as part of the Sales Cloud experience. This feature can be configured to use several different dates (e.g. opportunity or delivery date), quotas can be set, a rollup hierarchy for managers to view and manage their subordinates' forecasts, based on product lines or other attributes, etc. It's a very extensive system, so I'm only going to summarize here, but you should definitely check it out.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. It does a lot but sadly does not allow for monthly revenue splits